# Does MOD021km images from MODIS needs atmospheric corrections

Tags: envi, modis

I have downloaded some mod021km modis images and I want to work with them.

I want to know if these data need atmospheric corrections?

Perhaps something like FLASSH in ENVI or other methods.

I can convert hdf files using modis conversation toolkit and convert them to Radiance,Reflectance or brightness temperature but I don't know if it needs any atmospheric corrections before converting.

Comment: I have just downloaded MOD021KM file. When I open it in ERDAS IMAGINE the datum is missing. It is not geographically referenced. How can I fix this? With this image, I want to use radiance reflectance and brightness temperature with atmospheric corrections.

Comment: [Sikandar](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/127706/sikandar), please ask this as a new question through GIS Stack Exchange. Thus, you will have much better chances to get an answer. It will be highly appreciated if you add a picture/code where it shows the datum problem.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145474)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MOD02 needs atmospheric corrections, if you need surface radiance you can use atmospherics parameters of other modis products. But if you need surface reflectance you can download (MOD09).

Read this [table](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/modis_products_table) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your help..No I just want to work on them and in this stage I want to find a relation between amount of PM10 and DNs..

Comment: Is there any manual about Mod01lkm data?The table you provided is about other modis products :(

Comment: you can read this resume of products (http://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/dataprod/dataproducts.php?MOD_NUMBER=01), im looking for the data specifications, but i don´t remember where it is. What are you looking for?

Comment: or read this http://mcst.gsfc.nasa.gov/sites/mcst.gsfc/files/file_attachments/M1054.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your help.I just want to find some informations for mod02 products in case of atmospheric correction using FLAASH ..like FWHM for bands and etc